# Need to select a row from Gridview and run a select query that displays results

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to this so please be kind! I want to be able to select a row from gridview (returned to `TextBox1`) and run this query:

```
Select grade1.Grade, grade1.Date FROM dbo.grade1 WHERE grade1.Host = ( TextBox1)  ORDER BY grade1.Date
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class Domain : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(my connection String);


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


            protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;


                TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;


            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you should beware of SQL Injection. See: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/how-sql-injection-can-be-possible-in-asp-net-websites/ By using the user-entered value directly in an SQL query, you are opening yourself to SQL Injection. Consider Stored Procedures or an ORM like Entity Framework

Comment: Are you wanting to rebind your grid? Or just display the selected value in a text box on the page? Try putting a breakpoint in your GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged method, and inspect the `sender` object. It should have the properties you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for the SQL injection tip Jonathan.  It doesn't matter if i rebind the grid or just display the value in a text box.